# why does gstreamer tag not cause c/c++ code highlight?

Tags: discussion, tags, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

When a question is tagged [gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer) it should, by default, cause C/C++ code highlighting - better then no highlight which is harder to read.

I know that gstreamer can be integrated via python / java or the question could be in just bash gst-launch command.

Is there any tag code highlight negotiation? gstreamer tag could have lower priority C/C++ language and if there is tag like python than this would be used instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be tagged with c++ as well if also python or java bindings exist?

Comment: @rene yes but I wanted to avoid "no formatting at all" ..

Comment: @otopolsky: so, make sure they're properly tagged. [tag:angularjs] questions don't automatically get JavaScript highlighting, either.

Comment: why so many downvotes? I think this is reasonable question.. and it happened to me that OP forgot to mark the language and the code was harder to read(I had to edit his answer tags and just 2/3 reviewers accepted.. then I had to wait) .. I think this leads to another discussion that there should be a mechanism helping users to choose also language etc..

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, only the language tags affect a post's formatting. E.g., a post tagged with [junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit) won't cause the post's code to be highlighted as Java code unless it's also tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

The best solution, IMHO, would be to make sure any [gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer) questions are also tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: What about [tag:jquery] and some other big library/framework tags? (No rule without exception)